# Xamarin.Forms - Setting a consistent background for MasterDetailPage app

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm building a mobile app as a learning/hobby project and was curious about how far I can push the designs in a xamarin app. Is there a way to present a consistent backplane or image in an app that employs MasterDetailPage in the mainview? The effect I'm trying to accomplish is when each page is shown, which would have a transparent background, the app background never changes or is part of the page transition at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the pages in your project has the same background, you can create a **BaseContentPage** which have a `background image` or `backgroundColor` and then all other pages inherits from the `BaseContentPage` :

BaseContentPage:

```
public class BasePage : ContentPage
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        this.BackgroundImageSource = "logo.jpg";
    }
}
```

Other pages in your project:

```
public partial class Page1 : BasePage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xaminals:BasePage  xmlns:xaminals="clr-namespace:Xaminals"
                    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Xaminals.Page1">
    
    <xaminals:BasePage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </xaminals:BasePage.Content>
</xaminals:BasePage>
```

Then all the pages will have the logo image as the background image.

Answer (score 1):

A.

Since any page type (Shell, NavigationPage, ContentPage, etc) that derives from `Page` has a `BackgroundImageSource` property, you can define the value globally in App.xaml.

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" TargetType="Page">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundImageSource" Value="your_image.png" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

---

B.

Well, if you wanna apply it just for MasterDetail pages, you can just set the style for `NavigationPage` only.

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundImageSource" Value="your_image.png" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```